# SQL Server Selecting newest entry for each row

Tags: sql-server, date, select

I have a SQL Server Table like this :

```
id(autoincrement)
hostname(varchar)
group(varchar)
member(varchar)
datequeried(varchar)
```

The table is filled by a scheduled job that scans network for windows client PCs local admin group members.

- Network scans - 
  seams with the fact that it may happen that some of the stations are not available during scans.

The query that I'd like to write is :

```
"select every hostname having the latest datequeried"
```

This is to display the newest result (rows) of each hostname queried on network.

Is it clear ? 
I'm still facing some syntax issues and I'm sure it is quite easy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE datequeried = MAX(datequeried)`?

Comment: I've noticed (and most answers seem to have ignored) that datequeried is `varchar` for some horrific reason. Can we at least hope it's storing the date(time) value in a string sortable fashion (e.g. YYYYMMDD or similar)? Could you modify the schema now to use a more appropriate data type (datetime or (assuming 20008) datetime2 or date)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on SQL SErver **2005 or newer** (you didn't specify...), you can use a CTE to do this:

```
;WITH MostCurrent AS
(
   SELECT
      id, hostname, group,
      member, datequeried,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hostname ORDER BY datequeried DESC) 'RowNum'
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable
) 
SELECT *
FROM MostCurrent
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

The inner `SELECT` inside the CTE "partitions" your data by `hostname`, e.g. each `hostname` gets a new "group" of data, and it numbers those entries starting at 1 for each group. Those entries are numbered by `datequeried DESC`, so the most recent one has the `RowNum = 1` - for each group of data (e.g. for each `hostname`).

Answer (score 1):

From SQL 2005 and later, you can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)() like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hostname ORDER BY datequeried DESC) AS RowNo
FROM YourTable
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNo = 1
```

"CTE" is a [Commom Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), basically just aliasing that first SELECT which I can then  use in the 2nd query.

This will return 1 row for each hostname, with the row returned for each being the one

Answer (score 1):

I can display the required results using :

```
   select hostname, member, max(lastdatequeried) 
   as lastdatequeried 
   from members
   group by hostname, member order by hostname
```

Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Please mark this as accepted if it is the correct answer. I've merged your unregistered account with your registered one, you should now be able to modify your questions, leave comments on answers you receive and accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select hostname,
       max(datequeried) as datequeried
from YourTable
group by hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hostname ORDER BY datequeried DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you want to find each station's most recent scan?
2. Or do you want to find every station that was  online (or not online)  during the most recent scan?

I'd have a master list of workstations, first of all.  Then I'd have a master list of scans. And then I'd have the scans table that holds the results of the scans.

To answer #1, you'd would use a subquery or inline view that returns for each workstation its id and max(scandate) and then you'd join that subquery back to scans table to pull out the scan row for that workstation id whose scandate matched its max(scandate).

To answer #2, you'd look for all workstations where exists a record (or where not exists a record, *mutatis mutandis*) in the scans table where scandate = the max(date) in the master scans list.